# How to search a multidimensional array for value?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which I would like to search. I found a method using $,map but I can't get this working.

My array is generated like this: (Using a PHP loop which gets the data from MySQL)

```
clientList.push = [{'ID' : '1', 'FullName' : 'Company1'}]
clientList.push = [{'ID' : '2', 'FullName' : 'Company2'}]
clientList.push = [{'ID' : '3', 'FullName' : 'Company3'}]
```

I am trying to use the following to return the "FullName" value Where ID = 2. This is an example from another question.

```
var found = $.map(clientList, function(item) {
    if (item.ID.indexOf('2') >= 0) {
        return item;
    }
});

if (found.length > 0) {
    alert(found[0].FullName);
}
```

However this doesn't return anything, and I don't get any Javascript errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"My array is generated like this"* I very much doubt it, not in JavaScript anyway. If it genuinely is, then that's your problem: Assigning to the `push` property doesn't add to the array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you explain? That is how I am generating the array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the clarification. I thought Push added new items to the array.

Comment: the `indexOf('2')` is very doubtful. it would match 2 as well as 20. check for equality. `push` will be a function, taking the element as an argument. as you are using it, it looks like you would try to replace the push method with the json content.

Comment: Do you *really* mean to have an array of arrays of objects?

Comment: @dlatikay In reality it's a unique 8 character code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My aim was to dumb a MySQL table into a Jquery array which can be searched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
clientList.push = [{'ID' : '1', 'FullName' : 'Company1'}]
clientList.push = [{'ID' : '2', 'FullName' : 'Company2'}]
clientList.push = [{'ID' : '3', 'FullName' : 'Company3'}]
```

You're assigning arrays to the `push` property, which is a method of the array.

If you have an array referenced from `clientList`, then to add to it you *call* `push` (no `=`, and note the `( ... );`):

```
clientList.push([{'ID' : '1', 'FullName' : 'Company1'}]);
clientList.push([{'ID' : '2', 'FullName' : 'Company2'}]);
clientList.push([{'ID' : '3', 'FullName' : 'Company3'}]);
```

Separately, that `$.map` code won't work, the entries in `clientList` don't have an `ID` property (they're arrays; the objects *inside* them have `ID` properties).

You've said in a comment:

> My aim was to dump a MySQL table into a Jquery array which can be searched

Then you *don't* want an array of arrays of objects, just an array of objects:

```
var clientList = []
// Presumably simulating the results of an ajax query
clientList.push({'ID' : '1', 'FullName' : 'Company1'});
clientList.push({'ID' : '2', 'FullName' : 'Company2'});
clientList.push({'ID' : '3', 'FullName' : 'Company3'});
```

To find the entry int here with `ID == 2`, you'd use `Array#find` (new in ES2015, but shimmable/polyfillable):

```
var item = clientList.find(function(item) {
    return item.ID == "2";
});
```

Live example:

```js
var clientList = []
// Presumably simulating the results of an ajax query
clientList.push({'ID': '1', 'FullName': 'Company1'});
clientList.push({'ID': '2', 'FullName': 'Company2'});
clientList.push({'ID': '3', 'FullName': 'Company3'});

var item = clientList.find(function(item) {
  return item.ID == "2";
});
console.log(item);
```

Comment: Many thanks, glad it was something simple and it makes complete sense now. (Very unwell today and had a last minute client change request before going live...)

Comment: @user2924019: Sorry to hear that. :-( Hope you're better soon. I've updated the above with what I think you want to do.

Comment: Many thanks, all working as planned now. (Doesn't help that there are three people inbetween myself and the client, that all speak different native languages. Not to mention I don't even work for the company anymore! Getting there at least. Cheers once again.

Answer (score 1):

The `push()` method adds new items to end of an `array`. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ppgrjxxg/#&togetherjs=JpQklDwhQU):

```
var clientList=[];
clientList.push({'ID' : '1', 'FullName' : 'Company1'})
clientList.push({'ID' : '2', 'FullName' : 'Company2'})
clientList.push({'ID' : '3', 'FullName' : 'Company3'})

var found = $.map(clientList, function(item,index) {
    if (item.ID == 2) {
        return item;
    }
});

if (found.length > 0) {
    alert(found[0].FullName);
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*. Also, `map` is the wrong tool here.